# Property 'findAncestors' does not exist on type 'Repository '

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Hi i have a problem with my typeorm code.

I followed the example from here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/tree-entities.md#materialized-path-aka-path-enumeration.

So my entity looks like:

```js
import {
    Entity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    Column,
    CreateDateColumn,
    UpdateDateColumn,
    Tree,
    TreeChildren,
    TreeParent,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
@Tree('materialized-path')
export class Category {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @TreeChildren()
    children: Category[];

    @TreeParent()
    parent: Category;

    @CreateDateColumn({
        type: 'timestamp',
        default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
    })
    public createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({
        type: 'timestamp',
        default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
        onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
    })
    public updatedAt: Date;
}
```

In my controller called 'CategoryController' i want to get the whole tree, but i get an error that 'findAncestors' not exists.

```js
import {  getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import {Category} from "../entity/Categories";

export class CategoryController {
    private categoryRepository = getRepository(Category);

    async getCategoryTreeBySingleCategory(category:Category|string){
        {...}
        return await this.categoryRepository.findAncestors(category); // <--- Property 'findAncestors' does not exist on type 'Repository '.
    }
}
```

Does someone know why and may help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member function `findAncestors` is only defined on type `TreeRepository` which you get by using `getTreeRepository` instead of `getRepository`.

Therefore write

```
import {  getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import {Category} from "../entity/Categories";

export class CategoryController {
    private categoryRepository = getTreeRepository(Category);

    async getCategoryTreeBySingleCategory(category:Category|string){
        {...}
        return await this.categoryRepository.findAncestors(category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhh, silly mistake. Thank you very much for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing a problem when he writes:

Category.find()

and get error find() is not defined or something like that then,

Import **BaseEntity** from **typeorm**

```
export class Category extends BaseEntity
```